# Changing class variables by means of a second and third class

Tags: java, class, variables

I'm working on a personal project and at the same time experimenting with it. I've got 3 classes contained in 3 files: Calculate.java, Geometry.java, and Test.java.

Geometry.java so far only contains some variables I want to work with, the get/set methods along with a constructor method.

```
package project;  
public class Geometry {  
    public static double length, width;  
    public Geometry() {  
        this.setLength(20);  
        this.setWidth(30);  
    }  
    public void setLength(double length){  
        this.length = length;  
    }  
    public void setWidth(double width){  
        this.width = width;  
    }  
    public double getLength(){  
        return this.length;  
    }  
    public double getWidth(){  
        return this.width;  
    }  
}
```

Calculate.java has a public variable of type Geometry and a method to work with the variables I created in Geometry.java.

```
package project;  
import project.Geometry;  
public class Calculate {  
    public static Geometry figure = new Geometry();  
    public static double area;  
    public void calcArea(){  
        this.area = figure.getLength() * figure.getWidth();  
    }  
    public double getArea(){  
        return this.area;  
    }  
}
```

Finally, in Test.java I'm creating a variable c1 of type Calculate.

```
package project;  
import project.Calculate;  
public class Test{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        Calculate c1 = new Calculate;  
        Calculate c2 = new Calculate;  
        c1.figure.setLength(55);  
        c2.figure.setLength(75);  
        System.out.println("L1: "+c1.figure.getLength()+" L2: "+c2.figure.getLength());  
    }  
}
```

The console output is: "L1: 75  L2: 75"

My interpretation of the output is that c1.figure and c2.figure are writing data to the same space in memory and thus, when I called `c2.figure.setLength(75)` it also altered `c1.figure.length`.

When I first wrote this code I assumed `c1.figure` and `c2.figure` would maintain their own separate values but they don't. Is there a way to achieve this (have `c1.figure` and `c2.figure` maintain their own values without altering the other)?

PS: First time I post here, I apologize in advance if I messed up the formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public static Geometry figure = new Geometry();
```

creates **one** Geometry object regardless of how many `Calculate` instances you have. Remove the `static` keyword (which enforces one instance per class) and each `Calculate` object will contain one `Geometry`.

The same applies to your `area` member, and the `length` and `width` in the Geometry object. I don't think in this scenario you require static anywhere (indeed, it's rare that I require it at all in small projects).

Here's the [tutorial section on instance variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), which is worth reading.

Comment: +1 as `static` is causing the problem.  Note that the `Geometry` class has its length and width declared as static variables too, which also needs to be fixed (else the same problem will occur at the next level of references).

Comment: @Brian Agnew - Thanks for the prompt answer. I've made the modifications and everything is working as intended. Thanks for the link, I'll give it a read before I continue coding.

Comment: @dtsazza - Thanks for the formatting edits and the clarification on the static issue.